# Executing a software on another network interface?

Tags: networking, ip-address

I have created 3 virtual interface on a Linux system, using different IP address.

I have a software doing requests to a server but it use the default interface, `eth0`.

Is it possible to execute a software using another IP address/interface temporarily, like `eth0:1`?

Something like :

```
USE_INTERFACE=eth0:1 node test.js
```

Answer (score 2):

This is usually up to the software to support. It is usually implemented by binding the socket to the IP address of the interface you want to use. Check the documentation for a way to bind to a local ip address.

If the software does not support that you have access to the source, you may add or alter the `bind()` call after creating the socket, so bind to the interface you want.

It may also be possible to hide unwanted interfaces with the control groups features, if your kernel supports it.

Answer (score 1):

You can override without touching to the software thanks to LD_PRELOAD.

I found that :

[Bind.c](http://www.ryde.net/code/bind.c.txt)

Compile it then :

```
$ BIND_ADDR="virtual_interface_ip" LD_PRELOAD=./bind.so ssh root@myserver.com
```

And it will use the virtual interface ip !

Then if you need to have multiple mac adresses on the same network card, you can use multimac :

[Multimac](http://www.primianotucci.com/default.php?view=57)

Happy hacking !

Answer (score 0):

Ok it's easier by using the same strategy than virtualization system. 
Using bridge mode, brctl, here is a tutorial :

http://www.lainoox.com/bridge-brctl-tutorial-linux/